# Controllability on nonlinear systems

Tags: control-theory, differential-algebra, nonlinear-system

Dynamic system in the book (chapter 6, page 67 in

http://www.me.berkeley.edu/ME237/6_cont_obs.pdf)

$$
\begin{cases}
\dot{x}_{1}=x_{2}^{2}\\
\dot{x}_{2}=u\end{cases}
$$
so

$$
        f=\begin{bmatrix}
        x_{2}^{2} \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix},
        g=\begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix},
$$

then

$$
C=[g,[f,g]]=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -2x_2\\
1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where $[f,g]$ denotes the Lie Bracket. Authors conclude system is not controllable because on $x_{2}=0$ $C$ loses rank. This is straigforward to prove since $\dot{x_1}>0$ so "I can't go back".

But let now consider

$$
\begin{cases}
\dot{x}_{1}=s(x_{2})=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x_{2}}}\\
\dot{x}_{2}=u\end{cases}
$$

where $s(x)$ is the well known [sigmoid function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) applying the same analysis we reach

$$
C=[g,[f,g]]=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -s(x_{2})(1-s(x_{2}))\\
1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

so C never loses rank, so it would be saying system is controllable. However always $\dot{x}_{1}>0$ so "I can't go back" just like in previous system so it's not controllable.

Am I missing something?

Comment: could it be that the condition "...C loses rank..." is *necessary* but not *sufficient* for *controlability*. I am careful with my response as it has gone many years since I was doing on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

In a non-linear system you should talk first about local accessibility, and from this point you can try to extend it to global or semi-global.

Note that C loosing his rank is a sufficient condition but not a necessary one. In your notes the authors says "if" and not "if and only if". Hence, there is not a contradiction in your question, you can have a "can not go back" and C being always full rank at the same time.